# Grep in R using conditions on the matching

Tags: r

I am using the tm in R and would like to change the stemCompletion function a little.
Currently when I have a string

```
    x <- c('everi','new')
```

and a pattern

```
   dictionary <- c ('every','everyone','new')
```

When I run the build in code in the stemCompletion, the function that is running is the following

```
   possibleCompletions <- lapply(x, function(w) grep(sprintf("^%s", w),
                                                  dictionary,
                                                  value = TRUE))
   structure(sapply(possibleCompletions, "[", 1), names = x)
```

and the result is

```
   everi   new 
   NA "new"
```

I want to change the function so that if the grep does not find anything for a particular value of x 
then it tries by taking out the last value of the string. In my case 'ever' instead of 'everi'
I tried this code but it does not work.

```
   substrLeft <- function(x, n) { substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-n) }

   possibleCompletions <- lapply(x, function(w) 

   if (grepl(sprintf("^%s", w),dictionary,fixed = FALSE) = FALSE) {
   grep(sprintf("^%s", substrLeft(w,1)),dictionary,value = TRUE,fixed = FALSE)
   } else {
   grep(sprintf("^%s", w),dictionary,value = TRUE,fixed = FALSE, invert = TRUE)
   })

   structure(sapply(possibleCompletions, "[", 1), names = x)
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have a few syntax problems.

1. First, `=` is assignment, `==` compares.
2. Also, `if` conditions in ℝ are, [according to the manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Conditional-execution) "a single logical value". So you could get around this by wrapping a comparison in parentheses (`(grepl(sprintf("^%s", w),dictionary,fixed = FALSE) == FALSE)`) but you'll get warnings since `grepl` produces a list of length 2.
3. Finally, your one-line function has expanded to several lines, so you'll need to wrap it in `{}`:

```
possibleCompletions <- lapply(x, function (w) {
+     if ((grepl(sprintf("^%s", w),dictionary,fixed = FALSE) == FALSE) ) {
+         grep(sprintf("^%s", substrLeft(w,1)),dictionary,value = TRUE,fixed = FALSE)
+     } else {
+         grep(sprintf("^%s", w),dictionary,value = TRUE,fixed = FALSE, invert = TRUE)
+     }
+ })
Warning messages:
1: In if ((grepl(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, fixed = FALSE) == FALSE)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if ((grepl(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, fixed = FALSE) == FALSE)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> str(possibleCompletions)
List of 2
 $ : chr [1:2] "every" "everyone"
 $ : chr "new"
```